# ReactJS Material UI withStyles incl. theme in TS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I tried to convert the Material UI Dashboard into TypeScript. https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/docs/src/pages/page-layout-examples/dashboard/Dashboard.js

Currently I'm facing the problem that the CSS style definitions cannot be set on withStyles function when exporting the Dashboard.

```
const styles = (theme: Theme) => ({
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
  },
  toolbar: {
    paddingRight: 24, // keep right padding when drawer closed
  },
  toolbarIcon: {
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    padding: '0 8px',
    ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
  },
  appBar: {
    zIndex: theme.zIndex.drawer + 1,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(['width', 'margin'], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
    }),
  },
  .....
});
```

If I correctly understand, I need this theme reference to adjust the style to the current Theme. But how do I get the current theme when calling the style function?

```
export default withStyles(styles(/*WHAT TO PUT IN HERE?*/))(Dashboard);
```

Answer (score 6):

`export default withStyles(styles)(Dashboard);`

`withStyles` will determine if it needs to call it with the theme or not.

`withTheme` or `withStyles(stylesObjectOrCreator, { withTheme: true })` is only required if you need to access the `theme` inside your component via props.

API: https://material-ui.com/customization/css-in-js/#withstyles-styles---options----higher-order-component

Answer (score 2):

Import `withStyle` from material-ui
and just use it as it is:

```
const style = withStyle((theme) => ({
    root: {
    display: 'flex',
    },
    toolbar: {
    paddingRight: 24, // keep right padding when drawer closed
    },
    toolbarIcon: {
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    padding: '0 8px',
    ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
    },
    appBar: {
    zIndex: theme.zIndex.drawer + 1,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(['width', 'margin'], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
    }),
  },
}));
```