# Re-adding styles to React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I've converted a function into a Class Component and now I can no longer use makeStyles to style my components. I'm trying to use withStyles instead but I'm not having much success. I've included my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {withStyles} from '@material-ui/styles'
import {db} from '../firebase.js'

import Accordion from '@material-ui/core/Accordion';
import AccordionDetails from '@material-ui/core/AccordionDetails';
import AccordionSummary from '@material-ui/core/AccordionSummary';
import AccordionActions from '@material-ui/core/AccordionActions';
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore';
import Divider from '@material-ui/core/Divider';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

import {makeStyles} from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';

//old
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
        width: '100%',
        flexGrow: 1,
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.default,
        padding: theme.spacing(3)
    },
    accordion: {
        margin: '-1px 0'
    },
    heading: {
        fontSize: theme.typography.pxToRem(14),
        flexBasis: '66.66%',
        flexShrink: 0
    },
    secondaryHeading: {
        fontSize: theme.typography.pxToRem(14),
        color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
    },
    eventDetailsBox: {
        marginBottom: theme.spacing(3)
    }
}))

//new
const styles = theme => ({
    root: {
        width: '100%',
        flexGrow: 1,
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.default,
        padding: theme.spacing(3)
    },
    accordion: {
        margin: '-1px 0'
    },
    heading: {
        fontSize: theme.typography.pxToRem(14),
        flexBasis: '66.66%',
        flexShrink: 0
    },
    secondaryHeading: {
        fontSize: theme.typography.pxToRem(14),
        color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
    },
    eventDetailsBox: {
        marginBottom: theme.spacing(3)
    }
})


let eventData = [];
const eventDataRef = db.ref('/events')
eventDataRef.on('value', snapshot => {eventData = snapshot.val()})

class EventAccordions extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            expanded: false
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    }

    handleChange = panel => (_, isExpanded) => {
        this.setState({expanded: isExpanded ? panel : false})
    }

    render() {
        const {classes} = this.props //undefined
        return (
            <div className={classes.root}>
                {eventData.map(event => {
                    return (
                    <Accordion
                        key={event.uid}
                        onChange={this.handleChange(event.uid)}
                        expanded={this.state.expanded === event.uid}
                        TransitionProps={{unmountOnExit: true}}
                        className={classes.accordion}
                    >
                        <AccordionSummary
                            expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
                            aria-controls={`${event.uid}-content`}
                            id={`${event.uid}-header`}
                        >
                            <Typography className={classes.heading}>{event.name}</Typography>
                            <Typography className={classes.secondaryHeading}>{event.humanDate}</Typography>
                        </AccordionSummary>
                        <AccordionDetails>
                            <Typography>stuff</Typography>
                        </AccordionDetails>
                        <Divider />
                        <AccordionActions>
                            <Button>Cancel</Button>
                            <Button color="primary">
                                Save
                            </Button>
                        </AccordionActions>
                    </Accordion>
                    )
                })}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(function ViewEventsPage() {
    return (
        <div>
            <EventAccordions />
        </div>
    )
})
```

I've pastebinned my old code [here](https://pastebin.com/dPFJzgCj)

How can I style the components (and children) inside a Class?

Additionally, 'theme' inside styles is undefined now, so how can I make use of theme.typography.pxToRem, theme.spacing, etc?

Thank you

Comment: "I think it is better to keep functional component. What was the reason to switch from functional to class based component ?" by @Zarrukh

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your `<EventAccordions />` component with the `withStyles`. With your current code, you're actually wrapping the `<ViewEventsPage \>` component, so `<EventAccordions />` never received any style.

Ideally, you want to create a separate file for `<ViewEventsPage />` (to organize your code) and there you can import `<EventAccordions />`:

**EventAccordions file:**

```js
export default withStyles(styles)(EventAccordions)
```

**ViewEventsPage file:**

```
import EventAccordions from "./eventAccordions.js" // (replace with your path)

const ViewEventsPage = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <EventAccordions />
    </div>
  )
}

export default ViewEventsPage
```

Comment: Hello, this makes sense! I've done this and it seems to be working fine, I was wondering if you were able to answer the second question regarding the 'theme' variable? Thank you!

Comment: Hmm, I was hoping this would make `theme` work :P
Maybe this other SO question can help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53198972/reactjs-material-ui-withstyles-incl-theme-in-ts
I am not super familiar with material-ui...